# Bmon hits segmentation fault

Tags: unix, segmentation-fault

I was wanting to check rates on a wonky connection and tried bmon - but it hit a segfault. Removing and reinstalling didnt help. Any thoughts on how to proceed?
This is with a standard install of ubuntu18 on a laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `bmon -i netlink:notc`

**Source**: https://github.com/tgraf/bmon/issues/42

Comment: @jeremy_rutman did my solution works? Would you please accept is a correct answer?

Comment: I was encountering the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 and this did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the similar problem. What I have observed is that this started occurring after the latest kernel upgrade. Prior to this I was able to run it without any problems.